# Bash wait on child process can return even when child process is still running

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script which spawns a child process in the background and waits on it(via wait command) . It also catches SIGTERM and passes it to the child. But whenever I send a SIGTERM to the parent process it comes out of the "wait"  even though the child is still running(child catches SIGTERM) . Is it possible to achieve truly waiting on a child from inside a shell script until the child dies?

Answer (score 1):

This is explicit behavior which common idiom depends on. Observe the following difference:

```
# this waits 10 seconds, and doesn't handle signal handlers until later
sleep 10

# this returns immediately when a signal is received
sleep 10 & wait $!
```

You're perfectly able to check whether remaining background tasks exist and wait again:

```
sleep 10 & pid=$!
while kill -0 "$pid"; do wait "$pid"; done
```

For a full discussion of signal handling, including the behavior described here, see [SignalTrap](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap).